# C# WPF AnimationClock for DataGridCell FontWeight

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

I want to have a AnimationClock to change the datagridcell fontweight.

I already do it on color, and it is working well, see below's code.

```
ColorAnimation ca = new ColorAnimation(Colors.Black, Colors.Yellow, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
ca.AutoReverse = true;

dataGridCell.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);                
dataGridCell.Foreground.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, ca);
```

But for the fontWeight they didnt provide dataGridCell.FontWeight.BeginAnimation method.

So I have to do a ApplyAnimationClock.
And I do it in this way but it fails.

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(400.0, 600.0, new 
    Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
da.AutoReverse = true;
AnimationClock ac = da.CreateClock();
dataGridCell.FontWeight = FontWeight.FromOpenTypeWeight(400);                
dataGridCell.ApplyAnimationClock(DataGridCell.FontWeightProperty, ac);
```

I want to change the fontweight from 400 to 600. But it give me this exception below.

Additional information: AnimationTimeline of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' cannot be used to animate the 'FontWeight' property of type 'System.Windows.FontWeight'.

My question is simple, I want to change the fontweight of the datagridcell, then after 3 seconds it turns back to normal. If there is a easy way to do this, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bold property:

```
dataGridCell.FontWeight = FontWeight.Bold;
```